# One-liner for splicing lists

Tags: python

I am looking for a pythonic way to splice two lists based on the values in one of them. One-liner would be preferred.

Say we have

```py
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

and

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

and the result has to look like this:

```py
[0, 'a', 'b', 0, 0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 0, 'f']
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `next` with `iter`:

```
d = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
d1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
new_d = iter(d1)
result = [i if not i else next(new_d) for i in d]
```

Output:

```
[0, 'a', 'b', 0, 0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 0, 'f']
```

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Thank you. To truly be a one-liner, I guess you could simply initialize `d1` as an iterator :)

Comment: Yes, `[i if not i else next(new_d) for new_d in [iter(d1)] for i in d]`.

Comment: Or `[i if not i else next(new_d) for i, new_d in zip(d, repeat(iter(d1)))]`, but I feel like that's probably worse.

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
d = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
d1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

print( [d1.pop(0) if i==1 else i for i in d] )
```

Prints:

```
[0, 'a', 'b', 0, 0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 0, 'f']
```

EDIT (More efficient approach):

```
d = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
d1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'][::-1]

print( [d1.pop() if i==1 else i for i in d[::-1]] )
```

Comment: The inefficiency of `d1.pop(0)` is probably worse than an extra line, though.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, one could reverse `d1` before and do just `d1.pop()`, it will be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [@Ajax1234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57431618/7690862), but on a single line:

```
d = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
d1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
result = [d[i] if not d[i] else d1[d[:i].count(1)] for i in range(len(d))]
```

Result:

```
[0, 'a', 'b', 0, 0, 'c', 'd', 'e', 0, 'f']
```

Comment: The constant copying of `d` makes this quadratic, which is a terrible tradeoff just to put it on one line.